# Problemas con la implementación de una clase abstracta en una subclase

Tags: c++11

Estoy tratando de utilizar [esta libreria](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/multimedia/twain/article.php/c1585/A-C-Wrapper-for-TWAIN.htm), pero tengo problemas, tengo la siguiente clase:

```
class CTwain {
public:
    CTwain(HWND hWnd = NULL);
    virtual ~CTwain();
    BOOL InitTwain(HWND hWnd);
    void ReleaseTwain();


    /*  
      This routine must be implemented by the dervied class 
      After setting the required values in the m_AppId structure,
      the derived class should call the parent class implementation
      Refer Pg: 51 of the Twain Specification version 1.8
    */
    virtual void GetIdentity();
    virtual BOOL SelectSource();
    virtual BOOL OpenSource(TW_IDENTITY *pSource=NULL);
    virtual int  ShouldTransfer(TW_IMAGEINFO& info) { return TWCPP_DOTRANSFER;};
    ...
}
```

Y debo implementarla a traves de una subclase:

```
class MyCTwain : public CTwain {
public:
    MyCTwain(HWND h) : CTwain(h)   // Call the superclass constructor in the subclass' initialization list.
    {
        // do something with bar
    }
    ~MyCTwain() {};
    void CopyImage(HANDLE hBitmap, TW_IMAGEINFO& info);
    void GetIdentity();
    BOOL SelectSource();
    BOOL OpenSource(TW_IDENTITY *pSource = NULL);
    int  ShouldTransfer(TW_IMAGEINFO& info);

protected:
    BOOL DisableSource();
    BOOL CanClose();
};



void MyCTwain::CopyImage(HANDLE hBitmap, TW_IMAGEINFO& info) {
}

void MyCTwain::GetIdentity() { std::cout << "getIdentity"; };
BOOL MyCTwain::SelectSource() { std::cout << "SelectSource"; return true; };
BOOL MyCTwain::OpenSource(TW_IDENTITY *pSource) { std::cout << "OpenSource"; return true; };
int  MyCTwain::ShouldTransfer(TW_IMAGEINFO& info) { std::cout << "ShouldTransfer"; return 1; }
BOOL MyCTwain::DisableSource() { return TRUE; };
BOOL MyCTwain::CanClose() { return TRUE; };

int main() {
    MyCTwain * t = new MyCTwain(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

El error que me arroja en pantalla el Visual Studio 2017 es:

```
LNK2019 símbolo externo "public: __thiscall CTwain::CTwain(struct HWND__ *)" (??0CTwain@@QAE@PAUHWND__@@@Z) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: __thiscall MyCTwain::MyCTwain(struct HWND__ *)" (??0MyCTwain@@QAE@PAUHWND__@@@Z)
```

Y:

```
LNK2019 símbolo externo "public: virtual __thiscall CTwain::~CTwain(void)" (??1CTwain@@UAE@XZ) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: virtual __thiscall MyCTwain::~MyCTwain(void)" (??1MyCTwain@@UAE@XZ)
```

Comment: ¿Has definido el constructor y el destructor de CTwain? El linker no los ve.

Comment: Gracias por comentar! Tengo que definir eso en la subclase MyCTwain? Con `CTwain(HWND h) {}
    ~CTwain() {};` alcanzaría entonces? En cuanto pueda lo pruebo... Pero no entiendo por qué debería redefinir constructores y destructores de otras clases en la subclase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CTwain {
public:
    CTwain(HWND hWnd = NULL);
    virtual ~CTwain();
```

En esta clase has definido un constructor y un destructor... luego debes darles una implementación para que el programa compile. Y esto es independiente de que luego la clase tenga herencia o que pretenda ser una clase virtual pura... si declaras un constructor o un destructor debes implementarlos.

```
CTwain::CTwain(HWND hWnd)
{
  // ...
}

// Si no usas memoria dinamica puedes forzar
// la implementación por defecto
CTwain::~CTwain() = default;
```